# Json Parse Error on sending a JSON string from IOS Native to Javascript (JSON.Parse)

Tags: javascript, ios, objective-c, json, wkwebview

Below is my JSON string which am sending from my iOS native code to java script, by calling evaluateJavaScript on WKWebView. But when I run the project I am getting an error stated below(am using WKWebview to show my html file).

JSON:

```
{
"config": {
    "APIUrl": "https:some Url",
    "provider": "ActiveDirectory",
    "UserDetails": {
        "UserName": "Test User",
        "FullName": "",
        "EMailAddress": ""
    },
    "formdata": [{
        "postData": "{\"args\":[{\"Name\":\"ProcessName\",\"Value\":\"offlineformios\"},{\"Name\":\"isSubmitForm\",\"Value\":true}}]}",
        "url": "https:Get Url",
        "type": "POST",
        "responseStatus": 200
    },{
        "postData": "{\"args\":[{\"Name\":\"ProcessName\",\"Value\":\"offlineformios\"},{\"Name\":\"isSubmitForm\",\"Value\":true}}]}",
        "url": "https:Get Url",
        "type": "POST",
        "responseStatus": 200
    }],
    "CDNURL": "file: Local file path",
    "queryString": {
        "PROCESS": "offlineformios"
    },
    "auth": "Basic test auth",
    "culture": "en-US"
  }
}
```

Error:

> WKJavaScriptExceptionMessage=SyntaxError: JSON Parse error: Expected '}', WKJavaScriptExceptionColumnNumber=32,

I have tried with jsonlint.com to check whether my JSON string is valid or not but it showing as valid. So I could not find any solutions,if anyone can help me out this that would be greate and I would expect the solution for this!Thanks.

Comment: _“which am sending from my iOS native code to java script”_ - and that means what exactly? How are you “sending” it, and who receives it where and how?

Comment: am using WKWebView(evaluateJavaScript).

Answer (score 0):

It may be an Issue with the escape char of PostData

```
"postData": "{\"args\":[{\"Name\":\"ProcessName\",\"Value\":\"offlineformios\"},{\"Name\":\"isSubmitForm\",\"Value\":true}}]}",
```

Comment: what you mean by escape char of PostData?

Comment: For example \" . (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Escape_character)
Try with empty PostData and see if the error happens again.

Answer (score 0):

Unexpected token at 235 which is

```
{\"args\":[{\"Name\":\"ProcessName\",\"Value\":\"offlineformios\"},{\"Name\":\"isSubmitForm\",\"Value\":true}}]}
```

So it may help to be run through the stringify and back:

```js
var JSObject = {
"config": {
    "APIUrl": "https:some Url",
    "provider": "ActiveDirectory",
    "UserDetails": {
        "UserName": "Test User",
        "FullName": "",
        "EMailAddress": ""
    },
    "formdata": [{
        "postData": "{\"args\":[{\"Name\":\"ProcessName\",\"Value\":\"offlineformios\"},{\"Name\":\"isSubmitForm\",\"Value\":true}}]}",
        "url": "https:Get Url",
        "type": "POST",
        "responseStatus": 200
    },{
        "postData": "{\"args\":[{\"Name\":\"ProcessName\",\"Value\":\"offlineformios\"},{\"Name\":\"isSubmitForm\",\"Value\":true}}]}",
        "url": "https:Get Url",
        "type": "POST",
        "responseStatus": 200
    }],
    "CDNURL": "file: Local file path",
    "queryString": {
        "PROCESS": "offlineformios"
    },
    "auth": "Basic test auth",
    "culture": "en-US"
  }
};
var JSString = JSON.stringify(JSObject)
var newObject = JSON.parse(JSString) 
console.log(newObject);
```